# 404 Not Found page nginx / 1.18.0

Tags: vue.js, nginx

There is an error while reloading **the 404 Not Found page
nginx / 1.18.0**

If you add the **#** sign to the link

*Example*: http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/url_page then the transition is made / How to fix it?

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        rewrite ^/([^\.]+)$ /$1 break;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://${BACKEND_ADDR}:${BACKEND_PORT}';
    }

    location /api/v1 {
        proxy_pass   http://${BACKEND_ADDR}:${BACKEND_PORT};
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
    }


    location /api/v1/ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://${BACKEND_ADDR}:${BACKEND_PORT};
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragment identifier in url will not send to nginx. Just forward root directory to backend.

Comment: Please give an example